# how to loop over this array to obtain only the number 6 and 2?

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to loop over the array called $res, but I want to obtain only the values 6 and 2, for each name it is an id, is its with a foreach o just a normal for? I am confused because the array has two arrays insiden and it increments if I add a new name like 'Joe'

```
$arrayDirectory = array('Nick', 'Alex');

$res = array();
foreach($arrayDirectory as $user) {
    $res[] = $obj->obtainID($user);
}

echo print_r($res);
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_usuario] => 6 [0] => 6 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_usuario] => 2 [0] => 2 ) ) ) 1
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: just print the values, I am trying to understand arrays in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$res[] = $obj->obtainID($user);
```

to

```
$user = $obj->obtainID($user);
$res[] = $user[0]['id_usuario'];
```

Comment: it works perfectly very complete

Comment: thanks you very much I still trying to understand arrays in php any advise??

Comment: Think of it like a chest of drawers, `$arrayOfDrawers = array('Socks', 'Jeans', 'T-Shirts');` - you have one item that contains a lot of different things. To get at your socks (first drawer), you want `$arrayOfDrawers[0]` which is just the drawer number, minus 1. T-shirts are in `$arrayOfDrawers[2]`. For multi-dimensional arrays, think of it like a grid. http://blog.elementsense.com/?p=249 offers a slightly more bizarre way of visualising it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($res as $item) {
    echo $item[0][0];
}
```

Or

```
foreach ($res as $item) {
    echo $item[0]['id_usuario'];
}
```

Depending on what you are looking for

With PHP5.3 you can also use `array_map()` with a lambda

```
$idUsarios = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item[0]['id_usario'];
}, $res);
```

Comment: Its only print 6 just one array, but your post it is interesting do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @King this would work if the data was in the format `array( array( arrayWithData() ) )` but it's `array( arrayWithSomeData(array()), arrayWithSomeData(array()) )`

Comment: Upped for the `array_map`, very clean solution